# How to make a function in Vanilla JS that puts checked attribute to the radio inputs before the selected input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox, ecmascript-5, preventdefault

I can't find solution for this one.

Need to put attribute checked on the inputs that are before the selected input with JavaScript and the inputs after it unchecked.

UPD: changed the input type to the "checkbox" and now I need a function that marks "checked" the checkboxes before the last checked one, while unchecking succeeding boxes in case they were checked before.

**Note:** The solution has to use ES5 compatible syntax.

With code examples, please !

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="product-1" name="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-2" name="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-3" name="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-4" name="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-5" name="toggle">
```

Comment: That's not what radios are for. Don't you mean checkboxes? Radio buttons are for single selections only.

Comment: Didn't confirm it, but I'm almost sure that it *is* checking the other radio buttons, but then they get unchecked once you check their following siblings afterwards.

Comment: Thought I can change their default behaviour, and make it work.

Comment: Nope. Sounds like bad practice. If you don't like the square style of checkboxes, it'd be better to try and customize their appearance, rather than trying to customize radio button behavior. Nice strat on your picture, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, its a Slint guitarist there)

It wasnt about the style of checkbox, but behaviour.
I've updated the question already.

Comment: That is perfectly doable. Just another question: let's say you click on the 4th and all 3 before it get checked. If you click the 2nd, do you expect the 3rd and 4th to be cleared?

Comment: Yes, I do!
that behaviour is what I expect.

Comment: Alright. I'm at work right now, so it'll have to wait a few hours. Probably someone will post a solution until then, though.

Comment: I will hope that would be you)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was a little late, but since nobody posted an answer - here you go. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, my friend, it can be as simple as this:

```js
// checkbox elements
var boxes = document.getElementsByName('toggle');

// function to bind to each of the input tags' change event
function markPreceding() {

  // retrieve the value from the clicked input
  var curIndex = this.value;

  // iterate through every single checkbox named toggle
  for (var i = 0, box = boxes[i]; i < boxes.length; box = boxes[++i]) {
    // if data-index is lower or equal to curIndex, then true; else, false
    box.checked = box.value <= curIndex;
  }

}

// add function to the onchange handler of each input
for (var i = 0, box = boxes[i]; i < boxes.length; box = boxes[++i]) {
  box.onchange = markPreceding;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="product-1" name="toggle" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-2" name="toggle" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-3" name="toggle" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-4" name="toggle" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-5" name="toggle" value="5">
```

#### Notes

<del>I stored each of the checkboxes' index using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).</del>

<del>I *could* have used the `value` property, for instance. I preferred using data attributes because you *might* want to use `value` for something else. It's your call.</del> (***see bottom of the post***)

We can retrieve each attribute `data-index` from the HTML view in JavaScript with `.dataset.index`. It could've been any other name instead of "index". Just remember that if you're using multiple words, such as `data-my-custom-prop` in HTML, you have to call it in JS as `.dataset.myCustomProp` (they get camelCased).

The `.checked` property stores a boolean anyways, so you can pass the comparison `box.dataset.index <= curIndex` that will evaluate to either `true` or `false`, respectfully checking or unchecking the box.

**EDIT:** Since you asked in the comments, I tried converting it to ES5 compatible syntax. I stopped using data attributes, for one thing, and I retrieved the input value with the `this` keyword, not `event.target` (maybe I didn't need to change this, but I get the impression that was more common back in the day).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir !
Just what i needed !

Comment: I've faced a problem, that i don't use Babel in my project and I can't use it for this project.
Can you show me how to use this in ES5 syntax, please ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check if that works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `<input type="radio">` is to allow only one of the inputs / options to be selected. Because of this, only the last input is being marked with your JS code. 
To be able to select multiple options, use `<input type="checkbox">`.
For more reference: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox).

Comment: Hello!
But i want to set a step progress bar, how can i achieve it with JS, code example will be very handy, thanks in advance